# List of the "catch all" questions

Tags: discussion, catch-all

We have certain questions on this site that that are "catch all" questions.  Such questions:

- Have a comprehensive answer
- Have all other questions about that topic marked as duplicate

I cannot find a complete list of these questions.

When a "catch all" question is proposed in meta, the meta discussion is tagged with [catch-all](/questions/tagged/catch-all).  Using that, we can list all the *proposed* catch-all questions.  However, there doesn't seem to be a way to list the catch-all questions that were actually created.  I know they many of the them show up on the [list of frequently asked questions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent), but they are mixed in with non-catch-all questions as well.

Can we figure out a way to have a list of all the catch all questions in a central, easily accessible place?

Comment: I think this question can become the repository for them

Comment: I put a community wiki answer on this question.  Should we also tag each of the questions as "catch-all"?

Comment: If we have a catch-all tag that would provide an easy way to keep track of them all

Comment: I think the tag makes a better list than maintaining a list here.

Comment: FYI, a common term for these kinds of questions on some other SE sites is "canonical questions".

Answer (score 2):

I put at [catch-all](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catch-all) tag on all the catch all questions.

Answer (score 1):

### List of Catch-All Questions

- [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)
- [Which Content Management System (CMS)/Wiki should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-wiki-should-i-use/25746#25746)
- [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)
- [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)
- [Which Ecommerce Script Should I Use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30150/which-ecommerce-script-should-i-use)